# Connect to wifi on boot Beagle Bone Black ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument

Tags: connection, wifi-configuration, wpa, beaglebone

I'm trying to configure a Beagle Bone Black to connect directly to an access point during boot.

I can manually bring up wifi connection with connmanctl. This works, but always loses connection after boot.

I tried to put a conf file in `/var/lib/connman`
This resulted in connmanctl connection not working anymore

I decided to disable connman with systemctl disable connman.service

And get it fixed in `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/wpa_supplicant/supplicant.conf`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp

wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supllicant.conf
```

```
network={
  ssid="my_wifi"
  scan_ssid=1
  proto=RSN
  key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
  pairwise=CCMP
  group=CCMP
  psk="my_password"
}
```

I also tried to handle it directly in the `/etc/network/interfaces file`

Adding wpa-ssid and wpa-psk there directly...

However:

Executing following command:

`sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -D wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -B`

I get following output :

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
```

Or if i configure a static ip in `/etc/network/interfaces`

With

`sudo ifup wlan0`

It brings up the interface, but does not connect to the access point..

Comment: Any specific reason to use `-D wext`? Does the BeagleBone Wi-Fi adapter not support the regular `-D nl80211`?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know, got it to work without that command.
Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. After talking to a collegue it magicaly startet working. But I reproduced it with my 2nd Beaglebone.
Providing the config source here:

/etc/network/interfaces

```
iface lo inet loopack
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.X.X.X
    netmask 255.X.X.X
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

```
network={
ssid="my_wifi"
scan_ssid=1
proto=RSN
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
pairwise=CCMP
group=CCMP
psk="my_wifi_password"
}
```

and disable connman

```
#sudo systemctl disable connman.service
```

Then after reboot it connects automatically